# Sequelize DataTypes.DATE changes SQL Server database column type to datetimeoffset

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

On my SQL Server table, I set the start date column with type datetime, and on the sequelize model, for this field, I still use `type: DataTypes.DATE`, however, when I enable `sequelize.sync`, that makes my database column type to datetimeoffset.

Does anyone know why?

Here is the relevant code:

```
projectStartDate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    field: "Project_Start_Date",
},
```

Comment: It tells you in [the docs](https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html), _(MSSQL) DataTypes.DATE now uses DATETIMEOFFSET instead of DATETIME2 sql datatype in case of MSSQL to record timezone. To migrate existing DATETIME2 columns into DATETIMEOFFSET, see #7201._.

Comment: Yes, I saw it was set to DATETIMEOFFSET on the source code. As our data column type is DATETIME, I can not switch to DATETIMEOFFSET and keep using DATETIME. How can I change or hack it?